# How to display image which is declared in object as a url and these object is stored in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
var employees =[{
                  name:"jacob",
                  age :23,
                  city:"virginia",
                  yoe :12,
                  image :'a.jpg'
               },
               {
                  name:"aaron",
                  age :21,
                  city:"virginia",
                  yoe :12,
                  image :'b.jpg'
               },
               {
                  name:"johnny",
                  age :50,
                  city:"texas",
                  yoe :12,
                  image :'c.jpg'
               },
               {
                  name:"jacob",
                  age :12,
                  city:"virginia",
                  yoe :12,
                  image :'a.jpg'
               }];
```

i want to access the image and display it on browser and i have kept these images in folder....what statement is to be required to display the images but only in javascript m a beginner.. please help

Comment: this is no valid json: `images = {`

Comment: Why the image is not an "attribute" of an employee?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `employees` variable should be an object to have a property named images; otherwise the images object should be stored without a key, arrays do not have keys;

This is how you create image element:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = employees['images']['employee1']['url'];
yourElement.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: thnx...but still i cant access it

Comment: @user1948425 `console.dir(employees)` - (At least in FF) The `images =` gets ignored and the images are added as the fifth element in the array without a "name". So `employees[4].employee1` should get you the image

Comment: hey Andreas now i ve changed the scenario please look at the code .. please tell me wat will be statement to display the image of each employee.

Comment: @ Andreas now i ve changed the scenario please look at the code .. please tell me wat will be statement to display the image of each employee

Answer (score 0):

With this new structure, you can just loop through the employees and get the image url.
A possible solution could be:

```
for (var i = 0, length = employees.length; i < length i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = employee[i].image;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```